# How to generate an API difference report (automatically)?

Tags: java, api

How can I compare 2 versions of some API (jar files or javadocs) and generate a report?
Example: http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/15/changes.html. Actually, how was this report done?

I've found jdiff.org, but it compares 2 generated xml-files, which is not convinient.

The main goal is to generate diff-report automatically when API is released

Thanks

Comment: As can be seen in the html source of those android pages, it is exactly http://www.jdiff.org that is used. What is inconvenient about it ?

Comment: Here is a similar question with a few answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337179/java-tool-to-compare-api-of-library

Comment: Inconvinience is that you should generate some xml-file for both versions and then compare this files. I thought that there is some way  to compare javadoc or public classes/methods from the jar file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised in comments **JDiff** is exactly what we needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Eclipse MoDisco](http://eclipse.org/MoDisco/) to create an [EMF model](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) instance of your Java Projects. Then you can use [EMF Compare](http://www.eclipse.org/emf/compare/) to create a diff between two different EMF model instances. When you apply an appropriate filter before doing the diff, you will get an API difference report.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to be very difficult solution) I think it will be hard to do it manually each time when API is released.

Answer (score 0):

In the Spf4j project the [API diff report](http://www.spf4j.org/spf4j-core/apidocs/changes.html) is generated with the [spf4j-jdiff-maven-plugin](http://www.spf4j.org/spf4j-jdiff-maven-plugin/usage.html). It is as simple to use as adding a plugin config in the reporting section like [at](https://github.com/zolyfarkas/spf4j/blob/master/spf4j-core/pom.xml#L555).

This way you will have the API diff report as part of the maven site and it can go back as many versions as you want.